# Returning large object from method runs 100x slower in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model for which I store a fairly large serialized object as one of its attributes.

When passing this object from one method to another i production environment, as can be seen from the logs below, takes a lot of time (100x to be precise).

Weird thing is, it doesnt occur in development environment, only production. Also it happens during an ajax request, but not sure if it's relevant

This is the piece of code invoking the method

```
    now = Time.now
    price_document  = self.applied_price_document
    Rails.logger.info "cp_id: #{self.id} self.try :applied_price_document (2) #{Time.now - now} "
```

Which logs 1.06 seconds

I then tried to log each instruction in that method to find the bottleneck, and it turns out there is none as can be seen from the logs

```
  def applied_carrier_product
    start = Time.now
    ancestors = CarrierProduct.find_carrier_product_ancestors(carrier_product_id: self.id).includes(:carrier_product_price).references(:carrier_product_price)

    parent    = ancestors.select{ |cp| cp.id == self.carrier_product_id }.first
    until parent.nil? || ancestors.empty?
      is_successful = parent.carrier_product_price.try('successful?')

      if is_successful
        Rails.logger.info "cp_id: #{self.id} end #{Time.now - start} "
        return parent.carrier_product_price
      end

      parent = ancestors.select{ |cp| cp.id == parent.carrier_product_id }.first

    end
  end
```

Just before returning the result, i log the total running time of the method, which results in 0.002 seconds.

This means that it takes about 1 second to pass the result to the invoking method. Given I call this methods up to 30 times in a row, this is a big problem

any idea as to why this is?

Comment: There is no way anybody can give you a decent answer as to why that issue occurs in one environment but not the other. There are _way_ too many variables, none of which we can check here. Do your dev and your prod database even contain the same amount of data? I would start with that `ancestors.select`; you could potentially instantiate thousands of Ruby objects there - that can't be good. This is probably something that should be done in the database query.

Comment: it's never more than 2/3 objects and besides, as evidenced by the logs, this is not the culprit. The slowdown happens when passing info from one method to another rhrough a return statement

Comment: That is highly unlikely. I would suggest installing profiling tools such as [rack-mini-profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) in order to get more detailed and reliable insights than a few timestamped log entries can give you.

Comment: It turns out the slowdown happens when accessing the serialized object from the model 'record.price_document', where price_document is the large object

Comment: So deserialization is the bottleneck? How big are we talking about? What database do you use, and how do you serialize / deserialize the object? What Ruby do you run?

Comment: Ruby 2.0.0, Postgres. I serialize the class using `serialize  :price_document`. Not sure how to get the size of the object though, but it's an object with a around 100 nested objects, each of which contains 5-6 attributes

Comment: If you're certain it's the serialization, I'd experiment with something more lightweight, such as serializing to JSON and saving it in a JSONB column (Postgres ~> 9.4). JSONB is quite powerful - you can index it, query it and return only parts of it you need.